# How to Requery a query?

Tags: php, mysql

consider "Query1", which is quite time consuming. "Query1" is not static, it depends on $language_id parameter, thats why I can not save it on the server.
I would like to query this "Query1" with another query statement. I expect, that this should be fast. I see perhaps  2 ways

1. $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM raw_data_tbl WHERE ((ID=$language_id) AND (age>13))');

   then what? here I want to take result and requery it with something like:

   $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM **$result** WHERE (Salary>1000)');
2. Is it possible to create something like "on variable based" MYSQL query directly on the server side and pass somehow variable $language_id to it? The second query would query that query :-)

Thanks...

Comment: You could use nested SQL queries, if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as your second idea.

For the first idea, though, I would go with a single query :

```
select *
from raw_data
where id = $language_id
    and age > 13
    and Salary > 1000
```

Provided you have **set the right indexes** on your table, this query should be pretty fast.

Here, considering the where clause of that query, I would at least go with an index on these three columns :

- `id`
- `age`
- `Salary`

This should speed things up quite a bit.

For more informations on indexes, and optimization of queries, take a look at :

- [Chapter 7. Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html)
- [7.3.1. How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- [12.1.11. CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for giving me right direction... I thought that there is something like query "precooking"... That above is indeed simple example where I would not bother to split query into 2 steps...

Answer (score 2):

With the use of sub queries you can take advantage of MySQL's caching facilities.

```
SELECT * FROM raw_data_tbl WHERE (ID='eng') AND (age>13);
```

... and after this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM raw_data_tbl WHERE (ID='eng') AND (age>13)) WHERE salary > 1000;
```

But this is only beneficial in some very rare circumstances.

With the right indexes your query will run fast enough without the need of trickery. In your case:

```
CREATE INDEX filter1 ON raw_data_tbl (ID, age, salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the best solution would be to just add conditions from your second query to the first one, you can use [temporary tables](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/02/04/using-mysql-temporary-tables-to-save-your-brain/) to store temporary results. But it would still be better if you put that in a single query.

You could also use [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/subqueries.html), like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...) WHERE ...`.